# Data type doesn't change after using astype

Tags: python, dataframe, types

I used this

> df.astype({'year': int} )

trying to change the data type of the column 'year' to int (it is currently 'object')
However, even after doing so, the column type doesn't change (it's still 'object')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you might want to assign it back to the year, this is not an in-place operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is inplace problem. Please use:

```
df['year'] = df.astype({'year': int})
```

So it works

Comment: Thank you! It worked :)